ERROR: check constraint "to_uppercase" of relation "my_table" is violated by some row
I try to run following script:
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT to_uppercase CHECK (upper(my_name) = my_name);

but when I do I receive the error:
 ERROR: check constraint "to_uppercase" of relation "my_table" is violated by some row

This error quite expected because on some rows I have value which contains lowercase symbols.
Is there way to define on conflict to replace values to upperase in the same statement?
P.S. I understand that I can search rows using
select ...
where my_name !=  upper(my_name )

and do consequent update but I would like to find a solution using single stetement

Are you asking how to search + update in a single statement (which is possible with UPDATE … WHERE …) or how to add the constraint and update rows violating it in a single statement (which is not possible)?

There is no ON CONFLICT clause for constraint definitions.

Try the following, so what I think you should do is make sure all data in the my_name column of my_table meets the requirement of being in uppercase before applying a new constraint, I proposed a two-step process wrapped in a single transaction for atomicity. First, an UPDATE statement is executed to convert all existing entries in my_name to uppercase where necessary, ensuring no current data will violate the new constraint. Following this, an ALTER TABLE statement is used to add a CHECK constraint that enforces all new or updated rows in my_name to be uppercase. This approach, encapsulated within a BEGIN and COMMIT transaction, guarantees the database maintains consistency and all entries adhere to the constraint requirements before it is enforced.
BEGIN;

-- Temporarily store the uppercased version that doesn't create duplicates
CREATE TEMP TABLE updated_names AS
SELECT my_id, upper(my_name) AS new_name
FROM my_table
WHERE my_name != upper(my_name)
AND upper(my_name) NOT IN (SELECT my_name FROM my_table);

-- Update original table from the temp table where no duplicates would occur
UPDATE my_table
SET my_name = (SELECT new_name FROM updated_names WHERE updated_names.my_id = my_table.my_id)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM updated_names WHERE updated_names.my_id = my_table.my_id
);

-- Handle remaining duplicates manually or via application logic

-- Add the constraint after resolving duplicates
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT to_uppercase CHECK (upper(my_name) = my_name);

COMMIT;


but what if there are 2 "my_name" with values
"qwerty"
"QWerty"

You can prevent duplicates by adding uniqueness constraints, before updating the entries to uppercase, you might want to first ensure that converting all values to uppercase won't result in duplicates if the column must maintain unique values. This can be handled by a pre-update check and then deciding on a strategy for any found duplicates, such as merging records or modifying them slightly then modify the update process to handle duplicates by adjusting the process to check for duplicates
